# Attaching Remote Event Receiver to Content Type

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, event-receivers

Looking through the SharePoint Client API I see no property which allows the attachmentment of a content type.  I was hoping to attach a remote event receiver to a custom content type on the installation event.  Does anyone have an approach?

Comment: We can all vote for this Feature here: https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/12508632-content-type-remote-event-receivers

Answer (score 1):

As of this time there is no EventReceivers property on the ContentType object in the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientObject namespace.  I would love to hear from the SharePoint product team why that property is omitted.  grr.

I am having to first add a ListAdded Event Receiver of which detects if my content type is present.  If it is a ItemAdded event receiver is attached to the list.

Comment: There seems to be an unsupported workaround here: https://sptalks.wordpress.com/2014/11/28/adding-an-event-receiver-to-a-content-type-with-csom/